# excel add blank last row if there isnt one already

Tags: vba, excel

How can add a blank row below the last used cell in column `A` but only add a blank row if there isn't one already?

> This is what I am working with.

```
Sub LastRowBlank()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim chkCol As Long

Set sht = Sheet1
chkCol = 1
LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row

    If .Cells(LastRow, chkCol).Text = "" Then 'If last row is blank then do nothing


    Else                                       'If last row is not blank then add blank row

    End If

With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
.SetFirstPriority
With .Interior
    Range(LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

> Thanks

Comment: You can not have `If...End If... Else... End If`. It should be `If... Else... End If`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell if you just put this in the 'Else' block you should be set.

```
Rows(lastrow+1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Then depending on how you want your borders to appear you might have to also do

```
Lastrow = lastrow + 1
```